# CSS flex display on the second row doesn't set even

Tags: css

I was just learning `display: flex`, so I'm trying to get used to it. The screenshot below was even before I removed the next content, now the last 2 items are not acting like the first row, don't know why, tried what I know but still.

```css
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
 .mainmenu {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

 .foodmenu {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
 
 }

 .foodmenu img{
  height: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .menutex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
 }
 
 .menuh5{
  font: 1.2rem bold;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #222;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
 }

 .menuh5 span{
  color: orange;
  float: right;
 }

 .per {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mainmenu">
        <div class="foodmenu">
            <div class="menutex">
            <img
            src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
            />
        <div >
            <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
            <div class="per">per dozen</div>
        </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="foodmenu">
            <div class="menutex">
            <img
            src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
            />
        <div >
            <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH   <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
            <div class="per">per dozen</div>
        </div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="foodmenu">
            <div class="menutex">
            <img
            src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
            />
        <div >
            <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
            <div class="per">per dozen</div>
        </div></div>
        </div>
        <!--last 3-->

        <div class="mainmenu">

            <!--Meat Kibbeh-->
            <div class="foodmenu">
                <div class="menutex">
                <img
                src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
                />

            <div >
                <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
                <div class="per">per dozen</div>
            </div></div>
            </div>


            <div class="foodmenu">
                <div class="menutex">
                <img
                src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
                />

            <div >
                <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH   <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
                <div class="per">per dozen</div>
            </div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="foodmenu">
                <div class="menutex">
                <img
                src="https://d1ouk4tp1vcuss.cloudfront.net/s3.amazonaws.com/ODNUploads/645966bbdb7c8Meat_Kibbeh.jpg?mode=crop&v=1&width=250"
                />

            <div >
                <div><h5 class="menuh5">MEAT KIBBEH <span><b>$18</b></span></h5></div>
                <div class="per">per dozen</div>
            </div></div>
            </div>
```

[image]The last two items were off from the position, if I add 3 items more, the last two were on the position.

Comment: Why is the second row contained within its own `div class="mainmenu"` that's inside the first row's `div class="mainmenu"`?  That's a very confusing structure.  Was that intentional?  (Getting rid of that seems to fix the problem.  Perhaps the whole thing is little more than a typo on your part?)

Comment: yep, you were right, I made the mistake of inserting the second row into my own "mainmenu". I will fix that and hope the issue will be gone.

Comment: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your markup like David indicated in the comment.

Your first "mainmenu" div isn't closed and there's also no closing div for "menu".

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <!-- foodmenu -->
  </div>
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <!-- foodmenu -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a cleaned-up codepen. Your CSS is fine, just the markup needs a little fixing.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/carbonspace/pen/jOddMMd)

Comment: yes, I already checked, David was right. I have fixed the issue. lol. thank you